# error: unresolved reference when trying to import a package

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create package in IntelliJ IDEA and it works, but when i try to run file with terminal it doesn't work.

I got some error message : "error: unresolved reference: util".
I put the code in the same directory, here's ny code :

// PersonA.kt

```
package util

class PersonA {
    fun greet() {
        println("...")
    }
}
```

// main.kt

```
import util.PersonA

fun main(args: Array<String>){
   val person = PersonA()
   val greet = person.greet() 
   println(greet)
}
```

Comment: I run your code and get the expected output "...\nkotlin.Unit". There maybe something you have accidentally ignored.

Comment: I put them both inside `src/`, maybe the same as you say "I put the code in the same directory", but I am not sure where you put them and whether this will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

add package name in PersonA.kt

```
package com.example.appname.util //change the com.example.appname with ur package name
```

and at main.kt

```
import com.example.appname.util.PersonA
```